# Why is this HTML code not vertically aligning in the middle in Outlook (HTML Email)?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

```
  <table width="378" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
              <tr>
                    <td height="30" width="50" bgcolor="#e8e8e8">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; font-family: serif; font-size: 14px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" height="30" valign="middle" width="300" align="left" bgcolor="#00aec7">This should vertically center!</td>
              </tr>
        </tbody>
  </table>
```

In Gmail this is centered but in Outlook, it's at the top of the colored bar. I also tried using `line-height` and `vertical-align` but the `vertical-align` does not work and `line-height` has to be put to a smaller size than it should be (20px seems to center it despite the TD being 30px tall) **which then makes it top aligned in GMail!**

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping the text in a paragraph and span tag and giving those a line height of 100% is the only change that fixed it. Outlook replaces all the HTML with its own interpretation of what it thinks is "correct" and a representation of the original code (*determined this change by viewing the message source*).

```
<p style="height: 30px; line-height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 14px;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 14px;">This should vertically center!</span></p>
```

Using a `line-height` with a "px", "pt" or "em" did not work. Only "100%" works.

Comment: For me working well next:
line-height: 100%; line-height: 24px; (for example)

First - for Outlook, second - for other mail boxes (in GMail working well)

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in thinking you're trying to vertically align the text?
In my test I increased the height of the first cell and added a line-height of the same height (to show it in Outlook) to properly test this and it's working fine for me...

You can see my Email on Acid test here: https://www.emailonacid.com/beta/acidtest/display/summary/s5uj5kkuZ6hdiYqCJpi2BgMA4zPCekmlukAfzgPSuF9rJ/shared

It's working in Gmail.com, outlook.com, Outlook 2003-2013 and on mobile.
Can you provide screenshots of your issue?

Comment: Is your answer the answer you provided yourself because I wouldn't suggest something hacky like line-height:100%;

Comment: it's the only thing that worked. i tried your answer and it didn't work. maybe it's a odd setting but multiple people on outlook 2007, 2010 saw it not work with your answer but work with my "hacky" one

Comment: Weird! Fair enough then. I would also look at any styles in your head or hierarchical tables and cells that could have something defined that is messing with your alignment